# I want to know the difference between ここに and ここは

Tags: grammar, usage

What is the difference between the following sentences:

> ここは　きょうしつ　です。
>   これは　きょうしつ　です。
>   ここに　きょうしつ　です。

Answer (score 2):

You can say ここは教室です, literally "This place is classroom", to mean "I/We/You are in a/the classroom", talking about the place you are now. For example you can use it like this:

> A: ここはどこですか？ "Where are we?"
>   B: ここは教室です。 "We are in a classroom."

You'd usually use これは教室です, literally "This is classroom", to mean "This/It is a classroom." You could be talking about a place you're in, a room in front of you, a photo or drawing you're looking at, etc. You can use it like this:

> A: これは[何]{なん}ですか？ "What is this? (pointing at a place/photo/drawing etc.)"
>   B: これは教室です。 "It's a classroom."

You can also say ここは教室です / これは教室です to talk about the purpose of a room, as in:

> A: これは何の部屋ですか？ / ここは何をするところですか？
>   "What is this room for?" / "What activity do you do here?"
>   B: これは教室です。/ ここは教室です。
>   "This is a classroom."

「ここに教室です。」 sounds unnatural to me. 「[place]+に」, literally "in [place]" or "to [place]", is used with the verbs of existence such as 「いる」「ある」「住む」 etc, or motion verbs such as 「行く」「来る」「向かう」「帰る」 etc. e.g:

> 「ここにいますよ。」 "I am here." (literally "(I) exist in this place")
>   「ここに来てください。」 "Please come here." (literally "Please come to this place")

Answer (score 0):

ここは　きょうしつ　です。
Here is a classroom.

これは　きょうしつ　です。
This is a classroom.

ここに　きょうしつ　です。
Wrong. There is no subject. です is a verb that requires a subject.

Comment: `です is a verb that requires a subject.` -- でも・・「お疲れ様です。」「さあ、出発です。」「久しぶりですね。」「あ、雨ですよ。」「そろそろ帰る時間です。」とか、主語ないですよね・・ （ところで、「です」って、"verb" なの？）